# Put quotes around strings between commas, but not numbers

Tags: text-processing, quoting, csv

So I have some text in a file that almost represents CSV format, but not entirely. I want to turn in into a CSV file though.

I have for example:

```
cuz,0,1,2,3,-4,abc,a b c,0
```

How can I turn that into

```
"cuz",0,1,2,3,-4,"abc","a b c",0
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That file is a CSV already.  Fields only need to be quoted when they themselves contain `,`, `"`, or a newline character.  If a field does contain a comma or newline character, then no script is going to be able to properly quote that field (in general)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***gawk*** approach:

```
gawk -i inplace -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ 
      if ($i!~/^-?[0-9]*$/) $i=sprintf("\"%s\"",$i); }}1' OFS=',' file
```

The `file` contents:

```
"cuz",0,1,2,3,-4,"abc","a b c",0
```

---

`-i inplace` - allows *in-place* file modification

`$i!~/^-?[0-9]*$/` - pattern matching only field that contains characters  except numbers

Comment: This is great! It does pretty much exactly what I want. Only problem is that it throws away my new lines, so after running that it's just one long string. Any way to prevent this?

Comment: @user1840352, extend your input example to make it clear in regard to newlines

Comment: `/[a-z]+( [a-z])*/` is a strange way to write `/[a-z]/`, and should probably be `! /^-?[0-9]*/`

Comment: @Gilles, how would a hyphen `-` help for such item `,a b c,` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Because the intent seems to be to put quotes around fields that aren't isn't a decimal integer, not just around.fields that contain letters. And I just realized I made a typo in my comment, I of course meant `/^-?[0-9]*$/` (i.e. an optional sign then some digits and nothing else).

Comment: @Gilles, ok, edited. I really thought it was about *put quotes around fields that contain letters* (reread the title). Thanks